# How to write a camel router with kafka avro serializer in kafka consumer

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-camel, avro, confluent-platform

How to write kafka avro serializer and desializer (i.e using io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer)

```
from("kafka:localhost:9092?topic=customer_payment&groupId=group1&specificAvroReader="+ true+
            "&keyDeserializer=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer&valueDeserializer=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.KafkaAvroDeserializer&schemaRegistryURL=localhost:8081")
    .to("file://C:/Users/Documents/camel-kafka?fileName=MyFile.txt");
```

Can anyone help what are the dependencies for kafka avro confluent serializer

Please ask if any details you needed

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're using maven. 
Add confluent repository:

```
<repositories>
<!-- confluent maven repo, required to find avro deps -->
<repository>
  <id>confluent</id>
  <url>https://packages.confluent.io/maven/</url>
</repository>
```

Add dependencies including streams serde if this is the case:

```
<dependencies>
<!-- avro -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
  <artifactId>avro</artifactId>
  <version>${avro.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
  <groupId>io.confluent</groupId>
  <artifactId>kafka-avro-serializer</artifactId>
  <version>${confluent.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

...
 Build plugin, if you're trying to generate java types from an Avro schema.

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <!-- avro -->
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.avro</groupId>
            <artifactId>avro-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${avro.version}</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>schema</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: The build plugin is only necessary when creating a Java class from a schema, not simply consuming data

Comment: @cricket_007 - yes, sure. I know that, but he asked for a kafka avro serializer and deserializer so I assumed he would need it ;) . But reasoning about it, it's indeed a good thing to make it clear for future reference to others, good point. Thank you.